# Are server-sent-events (SSE) supported over Tor?

Tags: javascript, server-administration, website

[Server Sent Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events)(SSE) are a new alternative method to enable browser-server communication. Since Mozilla is supporting this initiative in their browsers, can we use SSE with the Tor Browser? What about SSE compatible browsers operating over Tor in general?